# SQL how to select Columns with following column value

Tags: sql

I have a bunch of values in my table and there is a field for flags. Flag values can be Y/N/''(blank)/NULL

I have a query to extract data from table where flag is either

Y to display only Y results

N to Display N/''/NULL results

All to display All results

```
Declare @flag varchar(10)
set @flag='Y'
select * from my_tbl
where (my_tbl.flag = case when @flag='Y' then 'Y' end )
           or @flag='All'
           or (my_tbl.flag='N' or my_tbl.flag is null)
```

When i set @flag = 'Y', it gave me results for both flag=y and null values which is not what i need.

what can i change to have this code work like how i need it?

Comment: `or (my_tbl.flag='N' or my_tbl.flag is null)` the last line allows null values.........

Comment: `case when @flag='Y' then 'Y' end` if flag is Y it is already Y, no need to use `case`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `coalesce` function to make `null` and `N` to be equal:

```
select *
from my_tbl
where @flag = coalesce (nullif(my_tbl.flag, ''), 'N')
  or @flag = 'All'
```

Comment: You proably meant to put the `coalesce` around `my_tbl.flag` because `@flag` is always either `Y`, `N` or `All`, but `my_tbl.flag` can also be `NULL` or `''`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from my_tbl 
where @flag = 'All'
   or @flag = 'Y' and my_tbl.flag = 'Y'
   or @flag = 'N' and (my_tbl.flag = '' or my_tbl.flag = 'N' or my_tbl.flag is NULL)
```

Combine the value of `@flag` with the required value of `my_tbl.flag`

Answer (score 0):

I used a `CASE` in `WHERE` clause:

- if @flag is 'Y' then compare @flag with column flag.
- if @flag is 'N' I get the idea from @astentx answer (change column flag values '' and NULL into 'N'), and compare @flag with column flag values changed.
- if @flag is 'ALL' compare @flag with string 'ALL' (ever TRUE, return all table rows).
- if @flag has another value query return no rows.

```
Declare @flag varchar(10)
set @flag = 'N'

SELECT * 
FROM my_tbl
WHERE @flag = CASE 
                   WHEN @flag = 'Y' THEN my_tbl.flag 
                   WHEN @flag = 'N' THEN COALESCE(NULLIF(my_tbl.flag, ''), 'N') 
                   WHEN @flag = 'ALL' THEN 'ALL' END;
```